# MD5 encoding with different results

Tags: java, spring, security, md5

I've run into this weird issue with `MD5` encodings. Actually, before everyone jumps in to tell me not to use MD5: it's a legacy system and the algorithm has already been chosen.

Anyway - I have a `MySQL` table with the `MD5` hashed password stored. In the same table, the salt is also stored.

I have a test user, whose password is `"test"` and the salt is `"salt"`. Using MySQLs `MD5` function `(select md5('testsalt'))`, I found the hash to be `"315240c61218a4a861ec949166a85ef0"`. I also verified this expected result with the admin of an external PHP system that sends user information to our system.

In one module of the system, we calculate `MD5` hashes using this code:

```
    public static String md5EncryptString(String string, String salt) {
    MessageDigest messageDigest;
    String encryptString = string + salt;
    String result;
    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        messageDigest.reset();
        messageDigest.update(encryptString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8")));
        final byte[] resultByte = messageDigest.digest();
        result = new String(Hex.encodeHex(resultByte));
        return result;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        logger.error("NoSuchAlgorithmException in encryptString");
        result = encryptString;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This method outputs the exact same md5 hash.

I then configured an Md5PasswordEncoder in the Spring security part of this sytem and ran into problems, because it would not let me log in. By extending the `Md5PasswordEncoder` class and overriding the encodePassword() method with some logging, I was able to determine that it outputs a different md5 hash: "150671e7a5fb8ace58aaa012de7f9b5c" when given the same password `("test")` and salt `("salt")`.

Can anyone explain this or give me some hint on what might be causing this?

Comment: Same number of `iterations`?

Comment: If you're gonna use MD5, fine, but this "In the same table, the salt is also stored." is somewhat concerning. Why would you store your salt in your database? If your database is compromised, you salt is worth nothing

Comment: @19greg96: Looks like you have not understood the reason of a salt. It is just there to prevent rainbow-table attacks on the md5.

Comment: Are you sure the method that does not work builds the same input string `"testsalt"` as the other methods?

Comment: @trashgod The number of iterations seems answered by the current number of upvotes of your comment: 1 :) Which is of course not a very high iteration count.

Answer (score 6):

According to some sources on Github Spring merges password and salt this way:

```
return password + "{" + salt.toString() + "}";
```

See method mergePasswordAndSalt(..) in [BasePasswordEncoder.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.java)

Comment: You can find the method [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.java/#72)

Comment: Yep: `$ echo -n 'test{salt}'|md5sum` returns `150671e7a5fb8ace58aaa012de7f9b5c *-`